# Sprockets and rails-ujs: cannot load such file — coffee_script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I‘m using Rails without coffee-rails and using [Rails UJS](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/976224b4de70d0760d301d2e3d0d81794fc523b3/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) (Ruby on Rails unobtrusive scripting adapter). After upgraded to sprockets 4, got the following error:

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- coffee_script):

rails (976224b4de70) activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
rails (976224b4de70) activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
rails (976224b4de70) activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
rails (976224b4de70) activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
sprockets (4.0.0) lib/sprockets/autoload/coffee_script.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It‘s because Rails UJS is written in Coffee Script (https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/785427b88c01654a441b8a7ed602feb35358285b/actionview/app/assets/javascripts), so you‘ll need to use `coffee-rails` gem with sprockets.

If you cannot use coffee-rails, migrate to [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) then

```js
import Rails from "rails-ujs"
Rails.start()
```